# Set buffer contents as defined in header file macros

Tags: arrays, c, macros, memcpy

I have various array content "templates" of type `uint8_t` that I'd like to define in a special header file. Those content templates also have different lengths:

```
#define CONTENT_VARIANT_A { 5, 3, 8, 1, 4, 23 }
#define CONTENT_VARIANT_B { 1, 10, 2 }
#define CONTENT_VARIANT_C { 4, 39, 2, 39 }
// '0' is not a valid element value (=> can be used for loop termination)

#define CONTENT_MAX_SIZE = 20;
```

In my code, I'd like to have a method to set the content of an array buffer to one of those pre-defined values. This is my code so far, using `switch` and `memcpy`:

Method to set the content:

```
void SetBuffer(uint8_t *my_buffer, uint8_t chosen_content) {
  memset(my_buffer, 0, CONTENT_MAX_SIZE);
  switch (chosen_content) {
    case CHOICE_VARIANT_A: {
      uint8_t new_content[] = CONTENT_VARIANT_A;
      memcpy(my_buffer, new_content, sizeof(new_content));
      break;
    }
    case CHOICE_VARIANT_B: {
      uint8_t new_content[] = CONTENT_VARIANT_B;
      memcpy(my_buffer, new_content, sizeof(new_content));
      break;
    }
    case CHOICE_VARIANT_C: {
      uint8_t new_content[] = CONTENT_VARIANT_C;
      memcpy(my_buffer, new_content, sizeof(new_content));
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
// Buffer declaration (done once)
uint8_t my_buffer[CONTENT_MAX_SIZE] = { 0 };

// Buffer population + usage (executed multiple times, with varying values for 'chosen_content')
SetBuffer(my_buffer, chosen_content);
uint8_t i = 0;
while (i < CONTENT_MAX_SIZE && my_buffer[i] > 0) {
  // ...
  ++i;
}
```

I'm a C# programmer, and new to C; the code in `SetBuffer` seems overly complicated to me, but is the only thing my mind could come up with that should work (with regards to what I think I know about C), and that also compiles. Is it the correct way of doing what I want, or is it pell-mell and should be done completely different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case the zero-out isn't necessary, you can shave the function down to something like this:

```
void SetBuffer(uint8_t *my_buffer, uint8_t chosen_content) {
  
  switch (chosen_content) {
    case CHOICE_VARIANT_A: memcpy(my_buffer, (uint8_t[])CONTENT_VARIANT_A, sizeof((uint8_t[])CONTENT_VARIANT_A)); break;
    case CHOICE_VARIANT_B: memcpy(my_buffer, (uint8_t[])CONTENT_VARIANT_B, sizeof((uint8_t[])CONTENT_VARIANT_B)); break;
    case CHOICE_VARIANT_C: memcpy(my_buffer, (uint8_t[])CONTENT_VARIANT_C, sizeof((uint8_t[])CONTENT_VARIANT_C)); break;
  }
}
```

Where `(uint8_t[])CONTENT_VARIANT_A` is *not* a cast but together with the macro forms a *compound literal*. Essentially a local, anonymous temporary array. The `sizeof` expression is similar and calculated at compile-time.

If you *must* zero-out non-used cells, then replace `(uint8_t[])` with `(uint8_t[CONTENT_MAX_SIZE])`. C guarantees that items not contained in the initializer list gets set to zero.

Yet another alternative for speed over readability is an evil macro:

```
#define SetBuffer(my_buffer, content)         \
memcpy(my_buffer,                             \ 
       (uint8_t[])CONTENT_VARIANT_##content,  \
       (uint8_t[])CONTENT_VARIANT_##content)
```

Call as `SetBuffer(buf, A);` etc. It's fairly type safe since unknown letter prefixes will result in compiler errors. You might also want to ask yourself why you aren't simply using `memcpy` on the caller side.

Comment: Now that each case is 1 line, writing that on the caller side becomes an option. Before, the lengthy switch would've made the other function too long. I wonder - would the macro still be evil if I define it at the top of the C-file and undefine it at the bottom? Because honestly I think something like `LoadPreset(my_buffer, A)` improves readability over a function with very similar but long switch lines.